# SQL Server 2012 in Win8 connectivity over wan

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have a problem connecting over WAN to my SQL Server 2012 using port 1433. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, all protocols TCP/IP, Shared Memory, Name Pipes are enabled. And I disabled the firewalls of the machine where my SQL Server 2012 is installed. I also added an inbound port 1433 UDP and TCP. Configure the server local IP address to static 192.168.2.101 with subnet 255.255.255.0, add that local ip to Router Port Forwarding starting Port: 1000 ending Port: 1600. But when I tried connecting through global ip address its network related error. `GLOBAL_IP/ServerName`. How do I fix this? can someone guide me.

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise) did you install? The **Express** edition by default doesn't support **remote connections** (it can be enabled, though)

Comment: Im using version 11.0.2100.60

Comment: This version I guess is Sql Server 2012 Express Advanced 11.0.2100.60, but locally I can connect using the local IP address

Comment: Yes, and I said in my first comment: the **Express** edition by default **does not ALLOW** remote connections! You need to enable those explicitly.

Comment: I already check the features "Allow remote connections to this server"

Comment: @marc_s how to enabled the remote connection of express edition can you give me links or tutorial, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Google or Bing are your friends - there are tons of articles and blog posts explaining this - you need to learn to do your own research!

Comment: I already spent 3 days searching and trying/following numerous advice in the net, but still im not getting the result / connectivity.